# Symfony PHP 7 local host won't load anymore

Tags: php, symfony, localhost

I am running a PHP 7 development server with Symfony on a daily basis to work on a project (through VSCode terminal). Everything was working fine until yesterday, when I started being faced with an infinite loading time for any page I try to open on my local server. I cannot point to any specific thing that I changed that might cause this, and in fact I'm almost positive that whatever is causing this did not originate from any change that *I* could have made somewhere. I tried:

- Changing up the local host port number, and
- Running `server:start` instead of `server:run`,

but to no avail. Anyone know of a fix, or at least a relevant place to look at?

Sample run:

```
C:\Users\berthierm\Desktop\OSO\Code\ApproOSO>php bin/console server:run


 [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000


 // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[Sun Nov 22 10:17:51 2020] PHP 7.4.11 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

(Followed by an infinite loading time, of course)

**EDIT**

We might be making progress: I am now getting a page saying "This site can't be reached - 127.0.0.1 unexpectedly closed the connection" when I try to access a local webpage when my local host is running. Still a bummer, though. Any ideas for this case?

Comment: okay ... let's do this step by step. have you tried just adding `die("test")` at the top of `public/index.php` just to see if it's something unrelated? after that, move the 'die' down, to see where it stops working/turns infinite. that will at least narrow it down.

Comment: I just ran my local host and tried to access a page on it (after attempting a lot of stuff, including deleting `composer.lock`) and now I'm getting a "This site can't be reached" error, not the infinite loading anymore. Do you have suggestions for this ?

Comment: run `composer update` to update dependencies and install them, that should provide you with a "working" symfony again (no guarantees about the infinite stuff though)

Comment: I had the same problem: for some reason, my composer.phar had been deleted, reinstalling it (https://getcomposer.org/download/) and running `php composer.phar update` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to symfony server:start. Had the same trouble until change to symfony server:start

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, that's another thing I tried but did not work (I'll add it to my original post). It gives me this error: ```[ERROR] This command needs the pcntl extension to run.

         You can either install it or use the "server:run" command instead.```
And apparently, you can't install this extension on Windows.

Comment: EDIT: I actually just understood properly which command you meant for me to run. `symfony server:start` does start the server, but the page that opens at the root address still loads infinitely